# CMake: How to specify FLEX and BISON targets under different subdirectories

Tags: cmake, bison

My project could be simplified as following structure.

```
--+ project directory
  +--+ flex (subdir)
  |  +-- CMakeLists.txt
  |  +-- xxx.l
  |
  +--+ bison (subdir)
  |  +-- CMakeLists.txt
  |  +-- xxx.y
  |
  +--- CMakeLists.txt
  +--- other source files
```

Now I have separate `CMakeLists.txt` files for `flex` and `bison` subdirectory.

Within `CMakeLists.txt` in root directory I wrote

```
add_subdirectory(flex)
add_subdirectory(bison)
```

Within `CMakeLists.txt` in `flex` I wrote

```
flex_target(lex ... )
```

Within `CMakeLists.txt` in `bison` directory I wrote

```
bison_target(syntax ... )
add_flex_bison_dependency(lex syntax)
```

Here `lex` is the target of `flex_target` in another directory `flex`. `CMake` shows me `Flex target 'lex' does not exists.`. I am wondering how to tell `CMake` that I have a previously defined and dependent `flex` target in another directory? Thx.

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your CMakeLists.txt files, including where you do add_subdir().

Comment: I tried it and you're right, `add_flex_bison_dependency` doesn't find targets defined in other CMakeLists files.  Would you be willing to move your calls to `flex_target` and `bison_target` to the parent CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm willing to do that. However, `CMakeLists.txt` file in subdirectories could not find intermediate source files (generated by `flex` or `bison`) from macro like ${BISON_target_OUTPUTS}, which is bcz `flex` and `bison` generate this when we `make`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got a solution here (maybe it seems awkward).

It turns out (as I mentioned in my question) that CMake could not recognize `flex_target` in another sub-directory. To avoid this error again I tried explicitly DECLARING ANOTHER SAME TARGET in that directory. It works.

Within `CMakeLists.txt` file in `flex` sub-directory I wrote:

```
bison_target(syntax ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bison/parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.c)
flex_target(lex scanner.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/scanner.yy.c)
add_flex_bison_dependency(lex syntax)
```

Within `CMakeLists.txt` file in `bison` sub-directory I wrote:

```
bison_target(syntax parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.c)
flex_target(lex ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/flex/scanner.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/scanner.yy.c)
add_flex_bison_dependency(lex syntax)
```

That works for both directories. If either module needs an isolated test, just use macros to avoid including codes from another module.